# how to find the position of a cursor inside body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the cursor position inside body tag.Actually I want if the cursor position is inside the span tag having class edit, then I want to prevent the cursor from jumping to new line on pressing Enter key. And if the cursor position is out of the span tag,then the cursor will jump to new line on pressing enter key. I would be greatly thankful to you if you provide the solution with an example. 
I am not so strong in javascript.I know to stop the cursor jumping to new line. The code for this will be.

```
$('p').keydown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   });
```

But in my case, prevention should be only if the cursor is inside the span tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not mess with the functionality of standard UI components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var canPressEnter = true;
$("span.edit").on("focus", function(){
    canPressEnter = false;
}).on("keypress", function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (canPressEnter === false && code === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}).on("blur", function(){
    canPressEnter = true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/S6hzY/

If you don't need the flag from somewhere else, this will do:

```
$("span.edit").on("keypress", function(e){
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/S6hzY/1/

This works for me:

```
tinyMCE.init({

    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
    setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
        tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'keydown', function(e) {
            var existing = tinyMCE.get('elm1').getElement(e);
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            var spans = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().getElementsByTagName("span");
            if (spans.length > 0)
            {
               for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
               {
                  if (spans[i].getAttribute("class") === "AMedit")
                  {
                     if (code === 13)
                     {
                        e.preventDefault();
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
        });
      });
    },
         themes...
```

Comment: Thanke, your answer is awesome. Thank you very very much. You are great!

Comment: It works in normal body tag. but does not work in iframe, you have already helped me. Can you explain in case the span tag is inside the iframe having id my_iframe ? thanks

Comment: I have visited your site but your contact form does not work.I want to send you more detail about my question thanks.

Comment: @user2702406 I suppose you want to use this with tinymce?

Comment: I have used this function and I get the alert message. Please can you help how can I get the focus event of this span.So when the cursor is inside the span tag,the enter key should not move the cursor to new line. my funciton is :




function loadlistener() {
    var p_parent = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("p");
    setInterval(function () {
        if (p_parent.find('span').length && p_parent.find('span').hasClass('AMedit')) {

            alert('Class on!')
        }
    }, 200)
};

Comment: Do you have someplace I can see what's going on? It's gonna be hard like this.

Comment: Click the equation symbol in the tool,then there equation appears in the editor.Once the cursor is inside this span and press enter key, the equation splits and the cursor goes to new line.that is my problem and want to solve.Thanks brother

Comment: If you dont mind please click this link to download the editor.There is a main file for the editor demo.html. you can code in that file.

http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo.zip

The size if very small of the zip folder.So dont worry to download.
Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: Check my edit. This works because the span does not have the class when it looses the focus which is a good thing, and less complex.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it still deos not wrok for me.The corsor goes down again on pressing enter key.If it works for you,can you send me that file on my email id ??

Comment: I have used your code and istead of e.preventDefault, i put an alert message which i got. But e.preventDefault() did not work ? what would be your kind suggestion ??

Comment: This works for chrome. The problem might be something else for Firefox?

Comment: so what do you think about this ? why firefox is not able fot this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37833/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-user2702406)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no selection, you can use the properties .selectionStart or .selectionEnd (with no selection they're equal).

```
var cursorPosition = $('#myTextarea').prop("selectionStart");
```

Note that this is not supported in older browsers, most notably IE8-.

Comment: sorry i have updated my question.Actually if the span will be in editable body tag,and i have to find the postion of cursor either the cursor is inside the span or outside the span.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may be helpful to you.

```
$('#myarea')[0].selectionStart; // return start index of cursor
```

Comment: Actually I have to put a condition for it. That is if the cursor is inside the span tag, do some stuff.